# JavaFX - How to get ListView to Update Automatically?

Tags: java, listview

I am trying to get my ListView to update automatically, which normally wouldn't be a problem but the updates are being called from methods in a different controller. Here is my dilemma.

MainSceneController.java

```
package appController;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import appData.Admin;
import appData.Album;
import appData.User;
import appDesign.PhotoAlbum;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainSceneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    ListView<Album> listViewofAlbums = new ListView<Album>();
    @FXML
    TextField albumField;
    @FXML
    TextField numField;
    @FXML 
    TextField lastPhotoField;
    @FXML
    TextField photoRangeField;

    public static Album selectedAlbum;

    public void logout(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        PhotoAlbum.primaryStage.show();
        ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }

    public void addAlbum(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

        createStage(event, "PhotoExpress - Create New Album", "/appDesign/CreateAlbumDialog.fxml", 526, 249);

    }

    public void rename(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

        createStage(event, "PhotoExpress - Rename Album", "/appDesign/RenameDialog.fxml", 526, 249);

    }

    public void deleteAlbum(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

        createStage(event, "PhotoExpress - Confirm Delete", "/appDesign/DeleteAlbumDialog.fxml", 503, 141);

    }

    public void openSearchStage(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

        createStage(event, "PhotoExpress - Search", "/appDesign/SearchScene.fxml", 868, 534);

    }

    public void createStage(ActionEvent event, String windowTitle, String fxmlLocation, int x, int y) throws Exception {
        Parent root;
        Stage stage;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlLocation));
            stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle(windowTitle);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, x, y));
            stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            stage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
            stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/appDesign/icon.png"));
            stage.show();

            // ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        User temp = LoginSceneController.getLoggedInUser();
        listViewofAlbums.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(User.getUserAlbums(temp)));
        listViewofAlbums.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == null) {
                return;
            }

            albumField.setDisable(true);
            numField.setDisable(true);
            lastPhotoField.setDisable(true);
            photoRangeField.setDisable(true);

            albumField.setText(newValue.getName());
            numField.setText(newValue.getSize());
            selectedAlbum = newValue;



        }
        );

        listViewofAlbums.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }

}
```

Now, on this MainScene there is a "Rename" button which will popup a dialog in which you enter the new name of the album in question. This popup dialog is controlled by the RenameDialog.java below. I want to auto-update the listview after rename has taken place.

RenameDialogController.java

```
package appController;

import appData.Admin;
import appData.User;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.Node;

public class RenameAlbumController {

    @FXML
    TextField newAlbumName;

    public void renameAlbum(ActionEvent event){

        Admin.renameAlbum(MainSceneController.selectedAlbum.getName(), newAlbumName.getText());
        ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();

    }

}
```

I currently cannot access or refresh my listViewofAlbums variable from anywhere else except the MainSceneController. I've tried so many work arounds but nothing has worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way to trigger a ListView update, from "a different controller", is to send a Broadcast Message, and "catch" it in your main Activity.

Two steps:
1) In your "different controller" fire off a message indicating that the listview now needs updated.

2) In your relevant Activity containing the ListAdapter, create a listener to "catch" the message, and trigger an update...

**(1) To send a broadcast message:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(msgUpdateListView);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**(2) To catch the broadcast message (in an Activity):**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
  private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
  private ListAdapter listadapter;

  @Override
  public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    //initialise listadapter here...
    mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //we got a message, so update our listview...
            listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(msgUpdateListView);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause(){
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
  }
```

**Messaging Constant (filter) visible to both**
`final String msgUpdateListView= "MY_LIST_VIEW_NEEDS_UPDATING";`